# How to store the access token and refresh token in android studio?

Tags: rest, android-studio, android-volley, access-token, refresh-token

I'm implementing rest API using volley library for my android assignment and I want to know how to save the token because every other API needs the access and refresh token, Should I save it in a database? How do I access the stored token when calling other APIs?

This is my webApi class,

```
 public void login(String email, String password, final APIListener listener) {
      String url = BASE_URL + "/oauth/token";
      JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();

      try {
           JSONObject userJSON = new JSONObject();
           userJSON.put("email",email);
           userJSON.put("password", password);
           jsonObject.put("user",userJSON);
           jsonObject.put("grant_type", "password");

           Log.d("Json Object", jsonObject.toString());

           Response.Listener<JSONObject> successListener = new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                     try{
                          Log.d("th response",response.toString());

                         

                          Gson obj = new Gson();
                          Authentication authObj = obj.fromJson(response.toString(), Authentication.class);
                          Log.d("successObj",authObj.getSuccess());

                          listener.onLogin(authObj);
                     }
                     catch(Exception ex){
                          Log.e("Volley onResponse Error",ex.toString());
                          Toast.makeText(mApplication, "JSON exception", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                     }

                }
           };

           Response.ErrorListener errorListener = new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                     Log.e("Json Error Response",error.toString());
                     Toast.makeText(mApplication, "Invalid Login", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
           };

           JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, jsonObject, successListener, errorListener);




           mRequestQueue.add(request);
      }
      catch (JSONException exception){
           Log.e("Login exception",exception.getStackTrace().toString());
           Toast.makeText(mApplication, "JSON Exception", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

      }


 }
```

This is the activity class,

```
 //login
    EditText emailField = findViewById(R.id.email);
    EditText passwordField = findViewById(R.id.password);
    Button loginBtn = findViewById(R.id.LoginBtn);

    loginBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String email = emailField.getText().toString();
            String password = passwordField.getText().toString();

            final Model model = Model.getInstance(LoginActivity.this.getApplication());
            model.login(email, password, new AbstractAPIListener() {
                @Override
                public void onLogin(Authentication authentication){
               
                    if(authentication.getSuccess().equals("true")) {
                        model.setAuth(authentication);
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Login success!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                    else{
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Invalid Login!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store your access token in Shared preferences

```
 public static String gettitledecreption(Context context, String Key_name) {
    return PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).getString(Key_name, "");
}

public static void settitledecreption(Context context, String username ,String key_name) {
    SharedPreferences _sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = _sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString(key_name, username);
    editor.commit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Auth0 provides a utility class to store tokens. Its better to use that utility library. There are two classes you can use to manage credentials:

1. CredentialsManager stores data in plain text
2. SecureCredentialsManager encrypts the data before storing it, using
   a combination of RSA and AES algorithms along with Android KeyStore.

Link to documentation: [Auth0.Android Save and Renew Tokens](https://auth0.com/docs/libraries/auth0-android/auth0-android-save-and-renew-tokens)